# How to call Jira Rest API from Oracle APEX Page

Tags: oracle-apex, jira-rest-api

Requirement -

Below fields to be displayed on a `APEX` page for any `Jira` issue created.

1. Issue Number/Issue Id
2. Summary
3. Description
4. Status
5. Assignee

Example, user01 and user02 both having access to `Oracle APEX and Jira`. user01 created 3 issues and user02 created 5 issues in Jira. Now when user01 who logs into Oracle APEX, should see 3 issues and when user02 who logs into `Oracle APEX`, should see 5 issues on a APEX page.

https://jira.local.com/jira/rest/api2

I'm new to APEX Rest service call and request to all of you to provide some sample APEX code to call Jira REST API using username/password for the above requirement.

Thanks all.

Comment: I don't have experience using JIRA's REST APIs, but you will want to use `APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request` to make your calls. Test out the APIs using Postman or other API testing tool, then try to mimic that request using that function call.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar before. In my case, the goal was to get all the issues of project PRJ001 (Jira Project Key) from Jira and store them in a local database table (J_ISSUES), periodically, so I've created a Job that executed the following procedure from time to time:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           "JIRA_SYNC_ISSUES" as 

var_response CLOB;
var_counter number := 0;
var_total number := 1;
var_prj_key varchar2(10);

begin

    var_prj_key := 'PRJ001';
    var_total := 1;
    var_counter := 0;
    
    while var_total > var_counter
    loop
        apex_session.create_session (p_app_id => 107, p_page_id  => 1, p_username => 'USERNAME01');

        var_response:= apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
        p_url => 'https://yourcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="'|| var_prj_key ||'"&maxResults=100&startAt=' || var_counter || '',
        p_http_method => 'GET',
        p_credential_static_id => 'oud_rest'
        );


        SELECT JSON_VALUE(var_response, '$.total' RETURNING NUMBER) into var_total
          FROM DUAL;

        for i in (SELECT *
        FROM 
        JSON_TABLE(var_response, '$.issues[*]'
        COLUMNS (
             key VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.key',
             prj_key VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.fields.project.key',
             status VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.fields.status.name',
             updated VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.fields.updated',
             assignee VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.fields.assignee.name',
             time_spent NUMBER PATH '$.fields.timespent'
             )))
        loop
            begin
               insert into j_issues (jis_key, jis_jpr_key, jis_status, jis_updated, jis_assignee, jis_time_spent) 
                  values (i.key,
                          i.prj_key, 
                          i.status, 
                          to_timestamp(substr(i.updated,1,10)||' '||substr(i.updated,12,8),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
                          i.assignee, 
                          i.time_spent);
            exception
               when dup_val_on_index then
                  update j_issues
                  set    jis_jpr_key = i.prj_key,
                         jis_status = i.status,
                         jis_updated = to_timestamp(substr(i.updated,1,10)||' '||substr(i.updated,12,8),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                         jis_assignee = i.assignee,
                         jis_time_spent = i.time_spent
                  where  jis_key = i.key;
            end;   
            var_counter := var_counter + 1;
        end loop;

    end loop;

end jira_sync_issues;
```

In the first part it is authenticating and making the call to the API. In the second, it takes the var_response and inserts it into the required table.
For the first part, I've read this: https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/simplifying-apex_web_service-oauth2-client-credentials
For the second: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm

Notice the var_counter and var_total variables. They are used to iterate through the Jira responses, because there is a limit of items being retrieved in each response. So, if you are expecting more than that limit, you should make more calls to retrieve them.

If the volume of issues is big, there are advantages in doing a scheduled sync like this instead of letting the user wait for the entire result. After the data is in your database, you can just query it as usual.

Let me know if it helps ;)

Comment: Thank you very much and appreciate for your help. I will follow your steps and let you know. Have a good day.